# How to get name of selected option in dropdown?

Tags: php

i want to get the name of selected option in dropdown.

I have a dropdown that displays course names and id from database. Now I want get the name of that course where it implement in value. but in insert query  select not get name. How do i do that? Thanks

```
  <?php

     <select name='course' onchange=\"reload(this.form)\"><option value=''>Select one</option>";
              foreach ($dbo->query($quer2) as $noticia2) { 
              if($noticia2['id']==@$cat){echo "<option selected                                                value='$noticia2[id]'>$noticia2[class]</option>"."<BR>";}
            else{echo  "<option value='$noticia2[id]'>$noticia2[class] </option>";}
           }
     </select>";



   if(isset($_REQUEST['sub']))
    {

  $a=$_REQUEST['course']; //in this i want to insert name not id of select option 
    }


   ?>
```

Comment: Maybe `$_REQUEST['sub']` isn't set?

Comment: Hello this is all perfect @Luca i get id but i want to get name in select option thanks

Comment: :D haha that makes sense about this insensible act @Luca

Comment: Well then don't set the value to the ID?

Comment: yeah i did that when i submit that select otion insert in database insert id not value name. i didn't know where i am wrng :(

Comment: What do you want to insert into your database? `$noticia2[id]` or `$noticia2[class]`?

Comment: $noticia2[class]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server get's only the data in the `value` property and the `name` of the select element passed on requests, not the Name of the options. If you want to get the `class` instead of the `id`, use the `class` as the value:

```
echo "<select name='course' onchange=\"reload(this.form)\"><option value=''>Select one</option>";
 foreach ($dbo->query($quer2) as $noticia2) { 
   if($noticia2['id']==@$cat){
     echo "<option selected value='".$noticia2["class"]."'> ".$noticia2[class]".</option>"."<BR>";}
            else{echo  "<option value='".$noticia2["class"]."'>".$noticia2["class"] ."</option>";
    }
  }
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: Yes you are right and thanks, but this is not up to mark sorry. in select id is required because on id i did some function on it and also select value i show name which is $noticia2["class"] but i want without changing my  code in database insert name not id. Hope you understand once again thank you and please tell me how to do that??

Comment: So, what exactly do you want to get from the client side? Both, ID and the Class, or just the class, or just the id? How do these classes and IDs look like? Can you give me an example input as an edit to your question?

Comment: No i am sorry and i am wrong you are right, I didn't check your code properly your answer is correct what i want. again Sorry.